# Any way to migrate AWS m5 to c6i?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 that has a Marketplace AMI.

I have Jenkins installed on this EC2. It was identified that the CPU usage is quite high in the build processes and we wanted to change the instance type from **m5.large** to **c6i.large**, but we received the following error:

**AMI name**: *CentOS Linux 7 x86_64 HVM EBS ENA 1901_01-b7ee8a69-ee97-4a49-9e68-afaee216db2e-ami-05713873c6794f575.4*

```
"Failed to modify instance type for instance i-xxxxxxxxx.
The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported.Please see the AWS Marketplace site for more information about supported instance types, regions, and operating systems."
```

Any solutions to solve the problem? If not, any tips on how to migrate Jenkins to a new instance without losing any data/configuration?

Comment: Have you read the [AWS instructions on the subject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html)?